# Listview obscures linear layout in Android 2.3

Tags: android, layout

Developing for Android 2.3, I have a question regarding layouts. I use a vertival linear layout. Within, there are two images, a listview and another linear layout, this time a horizontal one. Somehow, the listview keeps scaling down all the way to the bottom of the view, obscuring the second linear layout. Removing the listview brings the right result for the second layout. I've used all height qualifiers for both layouts, but that doesn't change anything. Any ideas appreciated!

Best regards,
Marcus

Comment: Can you add the XML you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `android:layout_weight="1"` for the listview and 0 for all other components finally did the trick! thnx anyway!